# Spring inject environment variable value into a custom class (not String class)

Tags: spring, environment-variables, inject

Does anyone know how to inject environment variable to a custom class?

For example, I know @Value can be used to inject to a String class from environment variable or properties file

suppose I want to do the following:

```
// I want to inject region as US in environment variable
@value("${some_property}")
private static Region region;
```

Region class looks like:

```
public class Region {
    public static final Region US = new Region("US");
    private final String key;
    public Region(String key) { this.key = key }
...
}
```

I tried this way, but at runtime it gives me null value

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, your environment variable is not an object but just a simple variable like this :

```
public class Region {
   @value("${region.local}")
   private String local;
}
```